# OSX - Run script on Fast User Switch

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a way to detect a Fast User Switch event in OSX - Yosimite.  Upon detection, I'd like to execute an applescript or automator action.  Is there a way to detect this type of event?

Answer (score 1):

One possible method, although a bit complex and requires admin access is:

1. Wrap the binary that triggers switching with a script that touches some flag file, then
2. Create a launchctl agent that will run a script whenever it sees a change to the flag file

The binary for fast user switching is here:
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession

A good tutorial on launchctl is [here](http://launchd.info). Use the `watchPaths` key to specify the flag file.

I was not able to find a file that changes with fast-user switching already. If such a file exists, you can skip step 1 and use it with launchctl to trigger your script.