# Run script on OSX when doing fast user switching

Tags: macos

Is it possible to setup a script to run when users switch through fast user switching on OSX (El Capitan)?
Earlier on, one could use a thing like this: http://www.radiotope.com/content/os-x-how-perform-action-during-fast-user-switch - but this method has not been possible for years now.

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31800644/2836621

Comment: Or this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8790102/2836621

Comment: So compiling a service/daemon to handle user switching events seems like the only way to acomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert - someone else may know better... I was just trying to help out.

Comment: And I do appreciate the answer! :) I will go down that road, eventually, if no easier path turns up.

Comment: Could you achieve this? I tried sleepwatcher and control plane, but still cannot catch post-user switching event... can pre-catch user-switching with Alfred: just set a shortcut to fast-switch and run a script BEFORE switching, but for post-switching some external event/call required...

Answer (score 2):

After some tries in wrong directions I came up with this quite elegant solution. My aim was to start and stop VPN connection only for specific Mac user. You can add final binary to User's login items or create a user agent in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` More info: https://www.launchd.info/

You will need to be familiar with Swift and Xcode.

Create MacOS, Command line Tool project in Xcode and paste the following into main.swift

```swift
import AppKit

class VPNManager {
    init() {
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(becameActive),
            name: NSWorkspace.sessionDidBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(becameInactive),
            name: NSWorkspace.sessionDidResignActiveNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }

    @objc func becameActive() {
        print("Workspace became active... starting VPN")
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/networksetup"
        task.arguments = ["-connectpppoeservice","PrivateVPN (L2TP)"]
        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("start result:", output ?? "empty")
    }

    @objc func becameInactive() {
        print("Workspace became inactive... stopping VPN")
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/networksetup"
        task.arguments = ["-disconnectpppoeservice","PrivateVPN (L2TP)"]
        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("stop result:", output ?? "empty")
    }
}

let vpnManager = VPNManager()

print("VPNManager initialized")
RunLoop.current.run()
print("VPNManager exiting")
```